Grafana Loki Helm Installation, Pending Pods with: 0/2 nodes are available: 1 Too many pods, 1 node(s) had untolerated taint
I have the following Helm values for my Loki deployment running AWS EKS. I have 2 nodes, one which I want got general apps and other for my production apps.
yaml

serviceAccount:
  create: true
  name: loki-s3-storage-policy
  imagePullSecrets: []
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::1234567:role/AmazonEKS_EBS_CSI_DriverRole
  automountServiceAccountToken: true

loki:
  schemaConfig:
    configs:
      - from: "2024-04-01"
        store: tsdb
        object_store: s3
        schema: v13
        index:
          prefix: loki_index_
          period: 24h
  storage_config:
    aws:
      region: eu-west-1
      bucketnames: testing.api.logs.chunks
      s3forcepathstyle: false
  pattern_ingester:
    enabled: true
  limits_config:
    allow_structured_metadata: true
    volume_enabled: true
    retention_period: 672h
  querier:
    max_concurrent: 4

  storage:
    type: s3
    bucketNames:
      chunks: testing.api.logs.chunks
      ruler: testing.api.logs.ruler
      admin: testing.api.logs.admin
    s3:
      endpoint: null
      region: eu-west-1
      secretAccessKey: null
      accessKeyId: null
      s3ForcePathStyle: false
      insecure: false

deploymentMode: SimpleScalable

backend:
  replicas: 1
read:
  replicas: 1
write:
  replicas: 1

minio:
  enabled: false

nodeSelector:
  nodeGroup: testing-node-group-t3-large

tolerations:
  - key: "dedicated"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "production"
    effect: "NoExecute"

I ran the following command:
helm install --values .\values.yml loki grafana/loki -n loki
I also tried:
helm install loki grafana/loki-simple-scalable --set read.replicas=2 --set write.replicas=2 --set loki.auth_enabled=false --values .\values.yml -n loki
However, I constantly see the following warning in my pods:
bash
kubectl describe pod/loki-backend-0 -n loki
sql

Warning  FailedScheduling  4m18s (x2 over 9m25s)  default-scheduler
0/2 nodes are available: 1 Too many pods, 1 node(s) had untolerated
taint {dedicated: production}. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 1
No preemption victims found for incoming pod, 1 Preemption is not
helpful for scheduling

I added a taint to one of my nodes to allow scheduling only for production apps. My production app has the following toleration:
yaml
tolerations:
  - key: "dedicated"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "production"
    effect: "NoExecute"

I've tried adding the same toleration to my Loki values (see the bottom of the values), but it’s not working. Preferably, I would like the Loki pods to schedule on the non-production node, but at this stage, I just need them to run.
Can someone help me with the following?
How can I add the toleration to my Loki deployment?
How can I ensure Loki pods only schedule on non-tainted nodes?
